# How can I express a waveform or parabola with the peak(s) cut off/flattened?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I want the peaks of the wave or parabola (above a certain positive or negative threshold) to be flattened - to look like mountains or valleys with flattened tops and/or bottoms.

Is there a simple way to express this mathematically?  I understand that a square wave can be approximated by a Fourier series, but I am not sure if it will work.  I also know that with the Fourier series approximation you get ringing at the corners so it's not exactly the same as having everything above a certain point in the peak being flat.

Comment: Do you mean something like: If $M > 0$, then $$\operatorname{flatten}_{M}(f)(x) = \begin{cases}-M & f(x) < -M, \\ f(x) & -M \leq f(x) \leq M, \\ M & M < f(x),\end{cases}$$which is equal to $f(x)$ so long as $|f(x)| \leq M$, but is "chopped off" if $f$ goes outside that range? (Incidentally, the question doesn't seem related to differential geometry or differential equations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a piecewise function:
$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }x\in [-1,1] \\
x^2, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$